# How do I combine four countif and add them all in one cell?

Tags: algorithm, excel-formula

Hi guys I'm trying to combine different things together then I want to add them all together in one cell. Right now there all in separate cells.I tried just about everything I know, but nothing. i haven't done this kind complex formulas since 2007. How would I combine these?

```
 =countif(b5:b32,"*")*5
 =countif(c5:c32,"*")*5
 =countif(d5:d32,"*")*10
 =countif(f5:f32,"*")*20
 =sum(b33,c33,d33,f33)
```

(Ps everything in the cells have dates I formatted the cells to text and formatted the cell that adds all of them to currency (g33). Also I formatted the cells that do the countif function to general just so it adds the cells and not date. My dates are in this format dd/mm/yyyy)

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the cells references in the SUM formula with the formula in each cell. Use this formula:

```
=SUM(
COUNTIF(B5:B32,"*")*5,
COUNTIF(C5:C32,"*")*5,
COUNTIF(D5:D32,"*")*10,
COUNTIF(F5:F32,"*")*20)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much it's so simply but I just forgot how to do it.